# Is it possible to add a slider without any object with Dat.gui?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dat.gui

I would like to have a shortcut for:

```
gui.add({zoom: 5}, 'zoom', 10, 200).name('Zoom').onChange(onChange)
```

something like:

```
gui.add(sliderType, name, min, max, onChange)
```

to handle the very common situations where I don't have any object to build the slider. On the opposite, I want to build new objects from the values of the sliders in my GUI.

For example, in a drawing app, the user needs to choose the parameters of the object he wants to draw/add, then he clicks to add it, and finally he wants to modify it by changing the sliders. This means that there is no object to build the slider, but all selected objects will be modified by the GUI on onChange events.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a JS object (POJO) as a go between to create and modify objects.

You don't always need to have a direct 1-1 relationship with the objects in the GUI and properties of objects in your application.

```
var objectProps = {x:0, y:0, radius:50};

GUI.add(objectProps, 'x', ...).onChange(changeSelected); //add sliders
...

function changeSelected() {
  //loop objects
  if (object.selected) //change props based on current values of objectProps
}

function createObject() {
  //use current values of objectProps as default props for new object
}
```

Comment: It is nothing I did not know already, but I did upvote your answer, thank you!

Comment: @mattdlockyer why do you bring up JSON? Don't you just mean a js object?